# How to select all users which is not followed any user with lambda expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, lambda

I'm new on lambda expressions, tried different variations of code but did not solve it and I have no any more ideas on how to solve this.

I have a user table which holds general information about user and the follow table which holds user IDs for each column (a column for a user who follows and a column for a user who is followed). I wanna select all users from users table which are not followed by a given user ID.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the database structure?

Comment: User table has primary key ID column and user detail columns. Follow table has 3 columns that row ID, follower ID and followed ID.

for example my user table ID is 1 and in follow table i follow the user whose id is 2. table is shown like ID=123 follower ID=1 followed ID =2

Comment: but there is multiple entry for the same user. i.e. for a single user, he may be follow 5 person and 10 person follow him. So how to handle multiple entries schenerio

Comment: I want to query only users which are not followed by given id so multiple entries schenerio is not important al least now

Comment: This is related to sqlserver only? and where the lambda expressions comes.

Comment: i'm using it in webservices with entityframework. Query returns xml data and use it in my java application.

Comment: If you wish,then I will give the sqlserver side code.

Comment: I will be appreciated if you share sqlserver side code 'cause i guess i can adapt it to lambda expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only sqlserver side code, which just have the logic for you application side.

```
declare @user table (id int, name varchar(50) )
declare @userdetail table (id int, followerid int , followedid int)

insert into @user values(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e')
insert into @userdetail values(1, 5,0),(2, 1,3),(3, 4,2),(4, 1,2)

/*to get followed list*/
select distinct name
 from @user u
inner join @userdetail followed on u.id = followed.followedid

/*to get un-followed list*/
select distinct name
 from @user u
 where u.id not in
(select distinct followedid from @userdetail )
```

Answer (score 0):

This example returns all users which are not followed by user with ID 3:

```
var result = context.Users.Where(user => !context.Follow.Any(follow => follow.followedID == user.ID && follow.followerID == 3));
```

But i recommend to creteate relations (foreign keys) between users and follow table. Then you can use a little clearer expression:

```
var result = context.Users.Where(user => !user.Followed.Any(follow => follow.followerID == 3))
```